# Союз И между двумя причастными оборотами в предложении Л.Н.Толстого

Tags: синтаксис

***...Навстречу шел большой обоз русских мужиков (1) привозивших провиант в Севастополь (2) и теперь шедший оттуда (3) наполненный больными (4) и ранеными солдатами в серых шинелях...***

На уроке подготовки к ЕГЭ предложение было дано без знаков, нужно было указать цифры, на месте которых должны стоять запятые. В ответах - 1,3. Дети овечают: 1, 2, 3.

Нахожу предложение: ...***Навстречу шел большой обоз русских мужиков, привозивших провиант в Севастополь, и теперь шедший оттуда, наполненный больными и ранеными солдатами в серых шинелях...*** (Л.Н.Толстой. "Севастополь в августе 1855 года")

**Как объяснить в этом предложении наличие союза И между причастными оборотами, относящимися к разным определяемым словам?** Разве они являются однородными? Можно ли сказать, что в предложении допущена грамматическая ошибка?

Comment: Ну ладно, не родился еще Розенталь, когда Толстой это писал, но составители-то заданий родились после Розенталя! По-моему, современные правила согласования слов в предложении не позволяют так писать. Я уже не говорю про "шел обоз, шедший"

Comment: Знаете как это должно восприниматься современным читателем: Навстречу шел большой обоз русских мужиков, привозивших провиант в Севастополь, и **поныне** шедший оттуда...

Comment: А рукопись доступна (похоже, и в других изданиях так)? Для меня выглядит как ошибка (возможно, корректорская) - с заменой _перевозивш**ий**_ на _перевозивш**их**_.

Comment: Возможно, угадал: вот задание с исправленным текстом: https://infourok.ru/material.html?mid=157387

Comment: Ещё один источник задания (там не предлагается четвёртая запятая): https://groups.dnevnik.ru/news.aspx?group=207391&news=326841

Comment: А в Нацкопрусе — привозивших: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CD%E0%E2%F1%F2%F0%E5%F7%F3+%F8%E5%EB+%E1%EE%EB%FC%F8%EE%E9+%EE%E1%EE%E7+%F0%F3%F1%F1%EA%E8%F5+%EC%F3%E6%E8%EA%EE%E2

Comment: У меня сборник рассказов Толстого 1984 года издания, там "привозивших" и "шедший".

Comment: Alex_ander, учителя, я думаю, сами исправляют предложение, когда готовят задание для школьников. Интересно, как было у Толстого. И почему).

Comment: Можно пофантазировать? Мужики привозили провиант в Севастополь поодиночке, а назад шли обозом. Или хотя бы так: не обоз формировался для доставки провианта, а отдельны мужики привозили провиант в Севастополь, а шли они туда обозом или нет - не имеет значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я посмотрела у себя бумажный вариант, там в таком виде :

...Навстречу шел большой обоз русских мужиков, привозивших провиант в Севастополь, и теперь шедший оттуда, наполненный больными и ранеными солдатами в серых шинелях...

Если ответ 1,3, то, скорее всего, прав Александр - просто опечатка, должно быть *привозивший и шедший*, ведь для учебных заданий часто текст "причёсывают" под необходимые правила, потому и пишут "по материалам рассказов Толстого", а не "По Толстому".

> Как объяснить в этом предложении наличие союза И между причастными
>   оборотами, относящимися к разным определяемым словам? Разве они
>   являются однородными? Можно ли сказать, что в предложении допущена
>   грамматическая ошибка?

По современным правилам синтаксиса - да, грамматическая ошибка, Л.Толстого часто обвиняли в неряшливости синтаксиса, но он не поддавался критике. Синтаксис Толстого построен по образцу синтаксиса французских аналитиков и использует все доступные средства сложного логического подчинения. Эта комбинация чистейшего разговорного словаря с очень сложным и логическим синтаксисом придает русскому языку Толстого особую индивидуальность. У него был свой взгляд на язык произведения:нарочитое несовершенство формы должно цеплять, тормозить чтение, заставлять углубляться в существо сказанного. В трактате "Что такое искусство" он пишет, что искусство ничего общего не должно иметь с красотой, назначение искусства в том, чтобы быть средством передачи чувства от одного человека другим.

По-моему, это предложение как раз это и отражает. Если бы он "причесал" предложение в соответствии с правилами построения предложения с однородными причастными оборотами, то получилось бы, что это обоз привозил провиант,а он хочет, чтобы мы поняли: **простые русские мужики** везли провиант в сражающийся Севастополь, а вот оттуда они же везли раненых солдат, но во второй части предложения важно передать, что **обоз был наполнен** ранеными. Однородные члены никак не подходили, потому он применил что-то вроде присоединения, а в целом всё равно всё смотрелось как предложения с однородными членами, ведь речь шла об одном и том же обозе русских мужиков. Получилась шероховатая неуклюжая фраза, а смысл верный - какой он хотел передать.

Это что-то вроде того, как согласуются некоторые формы подлежащих со сказуемыми. Если нам важно общее число считаемых предметов, мы ставим сказуемое в ед. числе: Несколько пуль провизжало над моей головой, если же это личности и нам важна каждая личность - ставим во множественное: Несколько незнакомых людей в мундирных сюртуках о чём-то толковали.

Такую свободу узаконили, а вот толстовские предложения считаем ошибкой. Видимо, гению прощается такая "неряшливость", просто её нужно понять, и уж никак нельзя использовать в учебных заданиях, поэтому подобные фразы приводят в нормативный вид. В данном же случае разработчики заданий ошиблись, выдали настоящую фразу Толстого.

Comment: Какая же Вы умница!

Comment: Спасибо! Просто я уже встречалась со стилем Толстого, пришлось искать. Удивлена, что его берут на ОГЭ.

Comment: Сомнений, что есть издания с таким текстом, нет; в сети тексты приводят по изданиям 1985 и 1996 г.г. (не считая учебных заданий, где в половине случаев изменено, если не взято из другого издания, окончание). Любопытно было бы посмотреть, что в берлинском издании 1917 года.